# Change the parent of QActions with... signals and slots?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a bunch of QActions, some of them are (for the moment) in two submenus and main menu.

As you can see in the code below, actions are created without parent **None** because the actions are shared to the buttons with a same menu.
That slot `on_connect` should create an instance of a class Wire.

The only thing that stops me to create an instance of wire class is `jack_connector`, that it should be the button which was pressed and shown the menu. The other parameters are okay, that's the only that I care for the moment. 
I figure out that I can obtain the value what I need with `self.sender().parent().objectName()` 
but at this point the QActions have parent set **None** , so that's why i need to set the button who shows the menu as the parent at runtime.

I already know that can be done with .setParent() method, but I don't know how to do that to all the actions, during the button press event.

Here it is the most relevant code:

```
scene = MyScene()
menu = QMenu()
widget_container = QWidget()

#dictonaries for dragbuttons (used later for connecting them)
jacks_dic = {}
inputs_dic = collections.OrderedDict()
wire_dic = {}

...
@pyqtSlot(str)
def on_connect(self,  input):
    print 'connected'
    jack_connector = self.sender().parent().objectName() #sender's parent of QAction should be the button
    wire_dic['wire_1'] = Wire(  jack_connector , widget_container.findChild( DragButton,  'btn_' + input ) , None, scene)

#Load Menu options for Jacks dragbuttons

#create sub-menus
submenus_dic = collections.OrderedDict()
submenus_dic['AIF1TX1_submenu'] = QMenu("AIF1TX1 (L) Record to Device")
submenus_dic['AIF1TX2_submenu'] = QMenu("AIF1TX2 (R) Record to Device")


actions_dic = collections.OrderedDict()
for input   in inputs_dic:
    #Create an Action
    actions_dic[ input  ] = QtGui.QAction( input, None)
    #TODO: Find a way to set parent a QAction after click
    #TODO: Research how to connect every action to a slot()
    actions_dic[ input ].triggered[()].connect( lambda input=input:  on_connect(actions_dic[ input  ], input)  )


    #Condition to add to a submenu
    if input[:-2] == 'AIF1TX1' :
        submenus_dic['AIF1TX1_submenu'].addAction( actions_dic[ input ] )

    if input[:-2] == 'AIF1TX2' :
        submenus_dic['AIF1TX2_submenu'].addAction( actions_dic[ input ] )

#Add SubMenus to Main Menu
for submenu in submenus_dic:
    menu.addMenu(submenus_dic[ submenu ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the one action is being triggered and you are trying to find out what menu was open and activated the action. There are several approaches that you can take.

You might want to explore the QAction's menu(), parentWidget() and associatedWidgets() methods with the QMenu's activeAction() method. You could also check what menu is visible.

QMenus create a widget representing the action when you add an action to the menu. So you could manually create these widgets and create a separate set of triggers to pass another parmeter into your function.

It really sounds like you need separate class.

```
class MyMenu(QMenu):

    newWire = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.wire_dic = collections.OrderedDictionary()

        self.action1 = QAction("text")
        self.action1.triggered.connect(self.action1method)
        self.addAction(self.action1)
    # end Constructor

    def action1method(self):
        # Maybe use self.windowTitle()
        self.wire_dic['wire_1'] = Wire(self.title(), widget_container.findChild( DragButton,  'btn_' + input ) , None, scene)
        self.newWire.emit("wire_1")
    # end action1method
# end class MyMenu

m1 = MyMenu("Menu1")
m2 = MyMenu("Menu2")

menubar.addMenu(m1)
menubar.addMenu(m2)
```

That way each object is associated with it's own action without you manually creating and managing a bunch of duplicate actions. This should be a lot easier to manage and the actions will all operate the same way.

Comment: slots needs to be inside a class? Even if it is the main window class?

Comment: I'm not sure that if that approach could help me. I need an slot able to receive not only the actions of a Qmenu, also needs to receive the drag n drop event

Comment: You can still call a regular slot method with m1.action1method(). In PySide you don't even have to worry if something is a slot. Any method can be a slot with the descriptor.